# Do I need to have an Apple developer account to implement interactions with Game Center?

Tags: ios, game-center

Do I need to have an Apple developer account to implement interactions with Game Center? Is it required? Can I implement leaderboards and achievements having only Xcode and the iOS simulator?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interaction with game center use your appID that is setup in your developer account. Long winded answer to say yes you do.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be clear about Apple, if you want to use a particular service, deploy an application, try an application in a real device, and a large etc, you will have to become an apple developer. If you are not a developer, you will be able to try your app in the simulator but anything else. That´s to summarize the "what can I do without an apple developer account"